# Jmeter removal of duplicate lines from csv file

Tags: csv, jmeter, jsr223

In jmeter using http requests i'm posting some json bundles and from the responses i'm using jsr223 post processor to extract data and store it inside csv files, each  entry in each line. now for 10 post requests i'm getting duplicate data into the csv file. Is there a way to read back csv files and remove duplicate lines using jmeter. The number of lines in csv files can be almost 200,000.

eg:csv file be like 
csvFile1.csv: 
line1
line2
duplicateline
...........so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can [read the file into an ArrayList](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) as

   ```
   new File('/path/to/file').readLines()
   ```
2. You can remove the duplicate entries using [unique()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#unique()) function as

   ```
   def lines = file.readLines().unique()
   ```
3. You can write the unique lines back using [Writer](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#withWriter(groovy.lang.Closure))

Putting everything together:

```
def file = new File('/path/to/file')
def lines = file.readLines().unique()
file.withWriter { writer ->
    lines.each {line ->
        writer.writeLine(line)
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Just in case: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: does the ArrayList hold 200,000 elements

Comment: Why not? It can hold up to [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,147,483,647) elements as long as you have enough [Java Heap space](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure). Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44hPl.png) of  adding 10M elements to the list

Comment: I was having this doubt, but you completely clarified it. Thank you sir